# Can CUDA permanently damage the GPU?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpgpu

I have not yet gotten into GPGPU programming, so I do not know the exact specifics of CUDA (OPENCL), but assuming that the GPU is in an optimal (well cooled,...) environment - can pure CUDA (OPENCL) code **permanently damage** the GPU? Is the GPGPU programming system robust enough to recover from all errors in the code?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060762/can-cuda-code-damage-a-gpu), but that one was rather posted because eaponte had a specific problem, that needed to be resolved. I am asking more in a general fashion.

Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: @talonmies care to enlighten me, why the question is silly?

Comment: @talonmies based on your profile, you obviously have a lot of experience in GPGPU programming. As there are multiple posts on the internet asking if it is possible to damage the GPU (usually coupled with CUDA code and a specific problem), there seems to be a misconception, that GPGPU programming -can- damage the GPU. I, and maybe some others in the future, would be grateful if you could answer my question, instead of tagging it off-topic and silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using Nvidia Tesla cards in development and production environments shared across many users in the last years, I did not see any "physically damaged" cards in this time due to "bad programming". So to empirically answer the first question: I guess if (also a GTX) is able to run Crisis in max. level without catching fire it should also survive your OpenCL/CUDA kernel on high load. Yes, vendors usually do take care of heat levels and reduce clocking, etc. as you know it from your CPU. Nevertheless, system manufacturers need a certification to make sure they can handle the produced heat, especially in multi-GPU systems.

But of course there have been several codes in the wild that damaged all kinds hardware in the past and this can certainly happen to GPUs, too - but I never read about a specific, code-driven case, although it would be an interesting research question.

Generally, GPUs can be damaged like any piece of silicon by simply using them. That happens from time to time, e.g., due to transistor ageing or overheating by bad cooling. We also replaced suddenly failing GPUs after several years in service the same way as we replace CPUs.

Since the initial question is rather broad one more addition: today's CPUs/GPUs/APUs/... contain so many transistors and production processes are so complex that it is often the case that not all components of a chip are actually usable (see.: PS3/Cell Processor with 7/8 active lanes; enterprise vs. gaming products, et al.). We actually had the case last year where a driver update rendered some previously "working" GPU into GPUs that now produced many double ECC errors. That was fixed again with an other driver update and only affected cards from early production cycles of a specific generation. One idea that we speculated was that the breaking driver did not mask "unusable" parts of the RAM correctly, a behaviour that is otherwise transparent to the end-customer.

> Is the GPGPU programming system robust enough to recover from all
>   errors in the code?

I can certainly answer this question with No. During development we have very often the case that frequent and "brutal" segfault-ing in a kernel can crash the driver. A full reboot of the host system is usually the only way how we recover in such a situation to make that specific GPU usable again.

Comment: To add to the last question: when a driver of a specific GPU crashed this might not result in failing cuda API calls but sometimes simply in utterly wrong computing results from kernels. During development, run a tool like cuda-memtest upfront your program to save some debugging time in such a scenario: https://github.com/ComputationalRadiationPhysics/cuda_memtest

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer - this was exactly what I was looking for.